# Getting wrong value from session in javascript, How to use session in javascript?

Tags: java, javascript

I am using following code to get session variable value in javascript  embedded in a JSP:

```
var numberOfPages= '<%=session.getAttribute("numberOfPage")%>';
```

I am getting a wrong value (old value) when I hit the page for the first time but when I refresh the page, then I'm getting the correct value. Please help me.

Servlet code:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false); 
if( session == null ) { 
   session = request.getSession(true); 
} 
String numberOfPage = Integer.toString(noOfPages);   
session.removeAttribute("numberOfPage"); 
session.setAttribute("numberOfPage", numberOfPage);
```

Jsp (javascript) Code:

```
if(<%=session.getAttribute("numberOfPage")%>!= null)
numberOfPages= '<%=session.getAttribute("numberOfPage")%>';
```

Comment: Java *or* JavaScript? Pick the language in which the issue resides (also, tag with JSP or whatever you're using).

Comment: what is that wrong value ? is it null?

Comment: first time wrong value means are you getting any values or not?Unless session is having any value,you can not recieve it getAttribute()

Comment: Not null. getting old value. At the time of set session i have removed that attribute and then set attribute but still it giving old value in jsp

Comment: it depends on how you are setting the session attribute, share the code and purpose.

Comment: servlet code:  HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
  if( session == null )
  {
   session = request.getSession(true);
  }
  String numberOfPage = Integer.toString(noOfPages);
  session.removeAttribute("numberOfPage");
  session.setAttribute("numberOfPage", numberOfPage);   jsp(javascript) code: if(<%=session.getAttribute("numberOfPage")%>!= null)
 numberOfPages= '<%=session.getAttribute("numberOfPage")%>';

Comment: Edit your question with the code. It's completely unreadable in a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

session.getAttribute() returns an Object, try to cast it.